# How can I get a consistent, unique, identifier for a unique class combination?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I need a way to identify a unique combination of template types that gives me an easily indexable identifier.

I have the following class:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::uint32_t IDType;

template<class T>
class TypeIdGenerator
{
private:

    static IDType m_count;

public:

    template<class U>
    static IDType GetNewID()
    {
        static const IDType idCounter = m_count++;
        return idCounter;
    }
};

template<class T> IDType TypeIdGenerator<T>::m_count = 0;
```

Which works, but when utilized across dll and exe, each "instance" in each process resets the count, so if in the .dll I have:

```
IDType id = TypeIdGenerator<A>::GetNewID<B>();
```

It will be a different value to the same call made in the .exe with the same two classes:

```
IDType id = TypeIdGenerator<A>::GetNewID<B>();
```

Of course, this only happens if the types for different classes are generated in different orders.

I understand that the static members are static across each process, and the dll is another process, so how else can I easily retrieve a unique id that's consistent?

I'd prefer to use standard methods, no special compiler extensions or flags etc.

EDIT: More info on my use case.

I have a template class that holds another type so I can operate on arbitrary data using that template type. Very simplified:

```
class ComponentBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ComponentBase() {}

    virtual void DestroyData(unsigned char* data) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void MoveData(unsigned char* source, unsigned char* destination) const = 0;
    virtual void ConstructData(unsigned char* data) const = 0;
};

template<class C>
class Component : public ComponentBase
{
public:
    typedef C type;

    virtual void DestroyData(unsigned char* data) const noexcept override
    {
        C* dataLocation = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<C*>(data));

        dataLocation->~C();
    }

    virtual void MoveData(unsigned char* source, unsigned char* destination) const override
    {
        new (&destination[0]) C(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<C*>(source)));
    }

    virtual void ConstructData(unsigned char* data) const override
    {
        new (&data[0]) C(*m_component);
    }
};
```

This is because instances of `A` or `B` need to be stored alongside each other in `unsigned char*` arrays. By storing a map of `std::unordered_map<IDType,ComponentBase*>`s I can keep access to all of the constructors, destructors, move operators etc.

I have a container that provides me information of which index in an `unsigned char*` is `IDType` for `A` or `B` etc.

So when operating on my data, I would have a container of `std::vector<IDType>` which from beginning to end provides me with every type stored in `unsigned char* arbitrary`.

I can use the IDType to lookup my `unordered_map<IDType, ComponentBase*>` so that I can operate on the type stored in `arbitrary`.

Obviously it's a little more involved than that or I'd just store the `ComponentBase*`s, but that's the general gist of why I need to be able to generate consistent type ids of some indexable type. Consistent only during the same execution of my program, not between different executions (though that would be a bonus).

I am using MingW64 delivered through MSYS2.

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is, more specifically?

Comment: @LayneBernardo I provided some more information but it doesn't really change the core need

Comment: I see, thanks for the context! If you are using Windows, you may check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/h90dkhs0(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks @LayneBernardo I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm using GCC/MingW so I'm not sure if that's really applicable here.

Comment: @LayneBernardo this is about sharing data between processes, not really applicable here.

Comment: Instead of a function-static `idCounter`, try a class-static variable. You will have to make `GetNewID` a class template rather than a function template. Not sure this will work.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The question is asking, unless I'm misunderstanding, about having shared static data between multiple processes using the same shared DLL. Although GCC/MingW probably means that it is not applicable.

Comment: @LayneBernardo No I don't think this is what's being asked.

Comment: Sorry @LayneBernardo I'm probably a bit confused about what counts as a "process". My exe links to several .dlls, and some dlls are linked to by other dlls. But the class above returns different IDs depending on whether the ID was requested within the dll code or exe code etc

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I can't use a class static variable because the function static is what allows it to be a combination of two classes. If it was class static it would be reset to zero for every unique pair of classes.

Comment: There are few things that will work regardless, however they don't really meet your use-case very well I don't think. For one, you could use some sort of IPC to share data, but you'd need to either implement that or use a third-party library. You could use a shared, locked file to store the IDs but that's sort of sloppy and not very efficient. You could use a database like sqlite to store the IDs, but this would also require a third-party library. Either of the last two could persist across executions, however.

Comment: Alternatively you could risk collisions and just perform some sort of hashing to generate a 'unique' ID instead of incrementing a counter. If the hashing function is good collisions will be extremely unlikely and this will be consistent across all executions regardless of context, *except* in the event that there is a hash collision, in which case you might end up with different IDs. For example, though, the UUID hash function has a collision rate of roughly 1 collision per 2.71 quintillion hashes.

Comment: I think I might need to be collate all types somewhere and sort of "register" them all together, though it would be very difficult to do now. I dig your idea on hashing the type, can you provide any info on how to hash a type?

Comment: While looking into this, I came across the following: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid . `type_info` has a hash_code() function which is guaranteed to return a unique hash for each type, although  the docs note that it can change between invocations of the same program so I'm not 100% sure this will work. `type_info` can also be used to get a unique type_index: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244491/discussion-between-neomerarcana-and-layne-bernardo).

Comment: The problem with Windows DLLs seems to be that each DLL gets its own set of class-static and function-static variables. This is against the C++ standard but that's what we have to live with. `type_index` should work.

Comment: Windows DLLs and unix shared-objects are almost the same thing, a class implemented within a binary (dll/so/exe/a.out) have there own copy of the code and data.  Libraries have generally used careful coding to ensure this appears appropriate for a given use-case, but that is by a mixture of template/header-file implementations to have per-binary implementation, and hidden run-time code referred by libraries to have per-process implementations.

Comment: @mksteve "Windows DLLs and unix shared-objects are almost the same thing". Yes, except when they aren't. This is one of the cases when they aren't.

Comment: You have to export the class for it to be shared with other DLLs. But you can't export a template because the DLL that would theoretically host the template doesn't know what types that template will be instantiated with. But for this problem, you can solve it without unique IDs at all. Instead of a vector of unique IDs, hold a vector of pointers to "serializers". Each class has a corresponding static "serializer" that implements the three virtual methods.

Comment: This is really exactly what a GUID is designed for... Upvoting Mr.Chen’s comment for this situation, tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of incrementing a counter to create the type IDs, you could instead use a hash function to generate a 'unique' hash. While there is some chance of collision, the risk is very low if the hashing function is efficient. This approach would provide consistent IDs for each type throughout an invocation of the program.

To this end, C++ actually provides a [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator which returns a [`type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) class instance. The `type_info` class implements a [`hash_code()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) function which is guaranteed to return a unique hash for each unique type.

The documentation notes that this hash can change between invocations of the same program, so this will not work across multiple different invocations.

The `type_info` class can also be used to get a unique [type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) which can be used directly to index into an associate container.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many of these types you are creating, but I would look for either of the following patterns.

1. ODR and small number of objects.

```
template<class T> IDType TypeIdGenerator<T>::m_count = 
                  (IDType)(void*)&TypeIdGenerator<T>::m_count;
```

This generates a base number on the location of a pointer to itself.  It doesn't cope with overflow into 2 different dlls, but if the number of types is small, this should keep the items separate.

2. Have some communication to a single source.

```
IDType generator()
{
     static IDType m_count = 0;
     return m_count++;
}
```

So in class

```
template<class T>
class TypeIdGenerator
{
private:

static IDType m_count;

public:

    template<class U>
    static IDType GetNewID()
    {
        static const IDType idCounter = generate();
        return idCounter;
    }
};
```

With `generator` being implemented in a single binary (DLL) all of the code will end up calling generator for its implementation, and Id's will be process unique.

Comment: Unfortunately I will have a large number of types. As for the second idea, that doesn't allow me to get a unique ID for a combination of types, and I wouldn't be able to call it for the same type twice and get the same ID.

Comment: A large number of types would be greater than 1000's.  The OS's we use at the moment run with at least 4k pages, which would mean that the addresses of a variable within a DLL / EXE are likely to be more than 4k apart.  So the seeded address of a variable in a DLL is probably good enough.

Comment: Make it threadsafe with atomic<> or ... locks.